# Configurable Products

Tags: configurable-product, swatches

Is there any way to use the simple products already in your product list with a configurable product?

Having problems with swatches too. does anyone know of a swatch extension that works well with the Infortis Ultimo theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For associting simple product with configurable, go to the configurable product, open the "Associated Products" tab, select the appropriate simple products and save. If you do not see your simple products there, make sure to click on "Reset Filter" (and that your simple products have the same attribute set as your configurable one). As always, you may need to reindex or clear your cache.

```
Note: Your simple product attribute should be same as your configurable
```

Try this swatches extension - https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Comment: Good idea. Would you happen to know what to set the `JS Callback` in the config to?

Answer (score 0):

YES. But the simple ones should have the product attributes assigned which you used for creating configurable product.

http://www.extensionsmall.com/color-swatch-with-zoom.html
try this. this is good.